# tvos uicollectionview relative focus

Tags: swift, tvos

Hello and thank you in advance for your help.

I'm learning tvOS and facing an issue related to the focus when navigating b/w the rows of a tableview. Each UItabelviewcell has an embedded collectionview.

for ex: if the focus is on the 3rd cell of of the 1st collectionview, swiping down to another row should keep you at the same index 3. Instead the focus jumps to the first cell of the collectionview for the second uitableviewcell.

Are there any properties I can use to achieve the expected behavior described in the image attached?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the UIFocusGuide as a way to control the focus? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifocusguide

Comment: I've managed to save the currently focused item but could not find how to use UIFocusGuide to focus the same index but in the second shelf. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Apple has some sample code here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UICatalogFortvOS/Listings/UIKitCatalog_FocusGuidesViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016433-UIKitCatalog_FocusGuidesViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_21

Answer (score 0):

That is because remembersLastFocusedIndexPath value is set to TRUE inside the collectionView of each TableViewCell.

```
myCollectionView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = false
```

This will make sure the focus works as expected.